# LaTeX page as figure

Tags: graphics, floats

I would like what is the package to get result as in page 227 (number printed in the pdf, page 245 of the file) of
[this](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/LaTeXpedia.pdf).

Comment: Do you mean the way to display the chapter number?

Comment: No, I mean in the "Figura 20" which is composed by four subfigures; each subfigure is a miniautre of a LaTeX page with a folding in the angle. Can you see them?

Comment: I can see the, I only messed up with the page numbers. I suppose these are scaled bibliographies with an overlay of a paper sheet. It can be done in various way (TikZ, pstricks, ).

Comment: Could you provide me a mwe? Thank you.

Comment: I do not have time at the moment, but I'll try later, if no one else posted examples.

Comment: BTW: The linked book, the 390 pages [LaTeXpedia](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/LaTeXpedia.pdf), is certainly worth a closer look! Unfortunately, it is written in Italian.

Answer (score 1):

The result isn't achieved with LaTeX: I've used OmniGraffle, a graphics program for Mac.

Lorenzo Pantieri